# Complexity of Estrin polynomial evaluation

Tags: algorithm-analysis

The Estrin model for polynomial of degree $n$ is well known. But the reading of the Knuth (vol 2) or the original's paper [Estrin](https://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/afips/1960/5056/00/50560033.pdf) do not help (or I miss it). I am not able to determine the complexity of the algorithm for the number of multiplication. The main equation is:

$$
\begin{align}
c_i^{(0)} &= a_i + x_0  a_{i+1}, \\
c_i^{(n)}     &= c_i^{(n-1)} + x_0^{2^n} c_{i+2^n}^{(n-1)}, \\
P(x_0)    &= c_0^{(n)}.
\end{align}
$$

and it leads for a polynomial of degree 10 to

$$
\begin{align}
P(x_0) &=  a_0 + a_1 x_0 \\
               &+  x_0^2(a_2  + a_3 x_0) \\
               &+  x_0^4(a_4  + a_5 x_0 + x_0^2 (a_6 + a_7x_0)) \\
               &+  x_0^8(a_8  + a_9 x_0 + x_0^2 a_{10}) \\ 
\end{align}
$$

For the additions: $n$

For the multiplication, it could be $n + \lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor$.

Can somebody confirm?

Best,

++t

Comment: Can you make your question self-contained by editing it to show the Estrin algorithm you are referring to?  Also, what does n represent?

Comment: It's not so clear what your $n$ is. Perhaps you can make your question even more self-contained by explaining what the "Estrin model" is, what $n$ is, and by giving a concrete example for small $n$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus $n$ is the degree of the polynomial to evaluate. I have updated my example for a polynomial of degree 10. With 10 addition and 13 multiplication following my proposition, but I am not sure at all

Comment: It seems that in your recursive formula, the degree of the polynomial is actually $2^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not particularly clear, but if I'm correct to assume that you're asking about [Estrin's scheme for polynomial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrin%27s_scheme) then Wikipedia confirms that it uses $n + \lfloor \lg n \rfloor$ multiplications.